# aspx web method returning a blank page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a WebMethod inside an aspx page which seems to be returning just a blank page, I don't think its even being called, what could be causing it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace Test.webservices.mainGrid
{
    public partial class getMainGrid : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public static string GetRecords()
        {
      return "test";

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What was the solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, it is callable by JavaScript (ASP.NET AJAX or jQuery for example). The text `test` does not render, because the page life cycle does not know what to do with this static method; since you have no markup on your page or logic to render to the page, then your page is blank at run-time.

Since the method is static it is not part of the actual page instance and thus cannot be called by code inside the page class itself. To that end, when you do call this from script, you will not have access to the other controls on the page. ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods are very useful for getting data from the server to use client-side.

To learn more about ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods read [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

I have used ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods extensively in my ASP.NET WebForms projects over the last several years. They are great for getting data from the server to update a piece of your user interface.

Comment: Hi, Yes I am trying to call this using jQuery (from another page). I have also tried it in a browser and I just get a blank page. Is this only callable from itself?

Comment: @realtek - no, you can call a page method from another page, but you must specify the page name and static method name in the URL (i.e. `YourPageName.aspx/YourPageMethodName`). Post the client-side code you are trying to use and I might be able to help more. :-)

Comment: @realtek - did you purposely make the page method return XML instead of the default JSON?